# `del` on a package has some kind of memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, package, del

`del` seems to have some memory which puzzles me. See the following:

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: math.cos(0)
Out[2]: 1.0

In [3]: del math.cos

In [4]: math.cos(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9cdcc157d079> in <module>()
----> 1 math.cos(0)

AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'cos'
```

Fine. Let's see what happens if we delete the whole math package:

```
In [5]: del math

In [6]: math.cos(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9cdcc157d079> in <module>()
----> 1 math.cos(0)

NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

So now math itself is gone, as expected.

Now let's import math again:

```
In [7]: import math

In [8]: math.cos(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9cdcc157d079> in <module>()
----> 1 math.cos(0)

AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'cos'
```

So somehow interactive python remembers that math.cos was deleted specifically even after we deleted the whole math package and imported it again.

Where does python keeps this knowledge? Can we access it? Can we change it?

Comment: I don't why he need it, but it is a good way to understand how it work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because they were previously asking [how to get the `math.cos` function back after deleting it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48808456/4042267).

Comment: @Graipher: My question stands. Why are they deleting things from the standard library _at all_?

Comment: 1) That you do it with a standard library does not implies that you may be interested in non standard libraries.

Comment: 2) It makes you understand how the library mechanism works, which could have implications in, let's say, time elapsed, use of resources, hard drive access, static variables in library, etc.

Comment: 3) It makes you learn how the interpreter deals with some issues, and transpolate it to another similar problems, or even make your once interpreter, or work into it to make it better

Comment: 4) Curiosity. It's the key that open the doors to knowledge. As my father says: breaking you learn. You never know how far your curiosity may take you. My father also says: the time of doubt is the time to learn (take any doubt as an inspiration to learn something). Also, it is interesting what Isaac Asimov said about curiosity when predicting Internet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would say that the package is still seen as imported. So performing `import math` again just redeclares the name, but with old contents.

You could use `reload` to make sure your module is whole again, except that some versions of python require to remove the entry in `sys.modules` as well, which makes the use of `reload` redundant:

```
import math
del math.cos
del math
sys.modules.pop("math")   # remove from loaded modules
import math
print(math.cos(0))  # 1.0
```

(this difference between various python versions, `reload` and `import` are discussed in a follow-up question: [Should importlib.reload restore a deleted attribute in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813320/should-importlib-reload-restore-a-deleted-attribute-in-python-3-6))

Comment: I'm afraid reload(math) does not re-introduce the math.cos function (at least on my machine). I have a separate question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808456/deleted-a-modules-function-on-interactive-how-to-re-import-importlib-reload-n

Comment: yes, I edited to show a version which works without reload.

Answer (score 62):

A package is only read from disk once and then stored in memory as mutable singleton. The second time you import it you get the exact same singleton you have previously imported, and it's still missing its `cos`. `del math` merely deletes the local name for it, it doesn't "unimport" the package from Python overall.

Comment: To add one more detail -- the second `import math` is going to look in `sys.modules` to find the loaded (and still mutated) module, and skip any attempt to load again from disk. You could try to delete it from `sys.modules` to force a reload, or use `importlib`, etc.

Comment: As I said in a comment below and elsewhere, reload did not helped me in python 3.6.4. Is this a reload bug or what? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808456/deleted-a-modules-function-on-interactive-how-to-re-import-importlib-reload-n

Comment: @Aguy I do not understand your comment. If you do `import math` then `del math.cos` then `reload(math)`, then `math.cos` is once again available, as `reload` re-executes the module initialization and re-populates the module's dictionary in `sys.modules`. One quirk about `reload` is that it will retain *extra* attributes. So if you manually created `math.foo`, then when you `reload(math)`, `math.foo` will remain.

Comment: @ely reload does not work in this case on my python 3.6.4. See the link in the comment above.

Comment: @Aguy Follow-up question [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813320/should-importlib-reload-restore-a-deleted-attribute-in-python-3-6) to look into the odd reload behavior in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 15):

`del math` does not delete the package at all, it just deletes the *local name* `math` in the current module.

Like any other object, if any other references to the math module exist anywhere, then it's kept in memory.

And in particular, `sys.modules` is always a dictionary of all loaded modules, so at least there's always a reference there.

Edit: But there's a way to actually reload a module, `imp.reload`.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work for this case, reload needs the random module (probably to create some part of the compiled Python file), the random module needs `math.cos`, and it's gone. Even with importing `random` first there is no error, but `math.cos` doesn't reappear; I don't know why, maybe because it's a builtin module.