# How does module reload in python3.7 work?

Tags: python, module, reload

## How does module reload work in python 3.7.1?

#### Setup and Summary

I am running python 3.7.1 in Linux. I am developing a C module, and it would be very handy to reload the module once it changed. I followed [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module), but I cannot get it to work in this environment.

For a demo of my problem, I wrote a simple module based on the SPAM example in the tutorial that returns the build time of the module. It will never get reloaded.

#### Code

The implementation is the spam example from the tutorial. It has a single function hello which returns the build time:

```
return Py_BuildValue("s", __TIME__);
```

I am compiling and loading with the following python script:

```
import os
import helloworld
print(helloworld.hello('test'))
os.system("touch helloworld.c")
os.system("python3 setup.py build")
os.system("python3 setup.py install --user")
from importlib import reload
helloworld=reload(helloworld)
print(helloworld.hello('test'))
```

The module is imported, the main file is touched, it is compiled and installed, and then reloaded.

#### Output

The module should show the new compilation time after reload, but the output does not change (I am leaving out some debug messages, the output is the first/last line, 08:04:20):

```
python driver.py
08:04:20
running build
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
gcc ...
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/helloworld.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> /home/wuebbel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Removing /home/wuebbel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/HelloWorld-2.1-py3.7.egg-info
Writing /home/wuebbel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/HelloWorld-2.1-py3.7.egg-info
08:04:20
```

Running the script again loads the correct module and shows the new time:

```
wuebbel@02e267406db3:~/Projekte/Mandelbrot Demos/helloworld$ python driver.py
08:16:58
...
08:16:58
```

It seems that my module never gets reloaded. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: you could try `sys.modules.pop("helloworld")`, then reload

Comment: I'd like to know if the workaround I provided works. I doubt it, according to other links I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have doubts about the feasability of reloading a module containing compiled code, reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814213/6451573 which suggests that [PEP 489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/#module-reloading) changed module reloading (between python 3.6 and 3.7), possibly "breaking" shared library reload.

> Due to limitations in shared library loading (both dlopen on POSIX and LoadModuleEx on Windows), it is not generally possible to load a modified library after it has changed on disk.

That could explain the problem you're having.

If this is an operational case, I suggest that you have a master python program which creates the package, then use separate python processes to load it.

subprog.py:

```
import helloworld
print(helloworld.hello('test'))
```

master.py

```
import os,subprocess,sys
def runit():
   subprocess.run([sys.executable,os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"subprog.py")])

runit()

os.system("touch helloworld.c")
os.system("python3 setup.py build")
os.system("python3 setup.py install --user")

runit()
```

Using `sys.executable` ensures that the same python executable is used for the master python process and the subprocess, so that's more transparent.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I agree that DLL reload is hard, but it generally should work - after all, it's in the official repo, and nobody else seems to complain - so I still think I'm doing something wrong (and it works fine in Matlab for mex files, if I remember right). 

Unfortunately, your workaround does not help, result is the same as before.

Comment: I have edited to propose a solution with a subprocess. Workaround too, slightly worse, but should work

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note that the API for subprocess.run has changed, I had to do something along the lines of `    print(subprocess.run([sys.executable,"subprocess.py"],capture_output=True))
`. While that works, it's not really what I need - Variables of the caller process get lost when calling a subprocess, I need interaction inside and more. I am currently concluding that I cannot get it to work the way I want it to. I am accepting your answer since that's the best one can probably do.